# Extending a continuous function to the closure

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm dealing with the following problem:

> Let $X$ a topological space, $Y$ a metric space and $A$ a subspace of $X$. If $f$ is a continuous mapping of $A$ into $Y$, show that $f$ can be extended in at most one way to a continuous mapping of $\bar{A}$ into $Y$.

Uniqueness is not a problem, existence is the difficult part for me. I did the proof for the case in that $X$ is a metric space one year ago, but it seems I can't use the same idea here. I hope someone could give me a hand. Tips will suffice, of course.

Comment: The key is that $Y$ is a Hausdorff space. Hence if two continuous functions $f,g\colon Z\to Y$ differ at a point $z_0\in Z$, they differ ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've forgot to say that uniqueness is actually not a problem, the problem is in the existence part.

Comment: For the existence, you need stronger assumptions. A map that is only continuous can in general not be continuously extended to the closure. Consider the case where $Y$ is an incomplete metric space, $X$ its completion, $A = Y$ and $f = \operatorname{id}$. But the problem doesn't ask you to prove existence, it asks you to show that it can be extended in _at most one way_, that is, it asks you to show uniqueness.

Comment: it says "at most" one way. So you don't have to show existence. This is good because I guess this is not possible. For example $D\supset int D \to int D$.

Comment: Ohh, that's right! I'm sorry, I didn't understand the problem completely. The problem is straightforward now. A good question  is under what hypothesis existence holds, Is it sufficient with $Y$ being complete? If we take $a\in \bar{A}$, is there a sequence $a_n\in A$ such that $f(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$?

Comment: The standard calc 3 counterexamples where you get different values of the function as you approach the origin are the intuition for why existence won't work in general.

Comment: A useful sufficient condition for existence of an extension is that $X$ is a metric space, $Y$ is a complete metric space, and $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: FYI: Here you find existence results: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989205/extending-a-bounded-linear-operator