# Isometric operators and boundedness on Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, isometry, unbounded-operators

Let $ T: D(T) \rightarrow \scr H $ be a densely defined isometric operator, i.e.
$$
\langle T \phi, T \psi \rangle = \langle \phi, \psi \rangle \quad \forall \ \phi,\psi \in D(T)
$$

```
notation:〈.,.〉is the hermitian inner product
```

Is there a sense in which $T$ can be bounded, even if it's not everywhere defined ($D(T) \subset \scr H$)?

Comment: Can $T$ not be extended to all of $\mathscr{H}$ by density of $D(T)$? Or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: If you put $\phi=\psi$ you get $\|T\phi\|=\|\phi\|$. Therefore, $T$ is continuous at $0$ and then continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $\phi = \psi$, we have $||T\psi||^{2} = ||\psi||^{2}$ so that $T$ is bounded on $D(T)$, with $||T|| = 1$. Now, [extend](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989205/extending-a-bounded-linear-operator) $T$ to $\mathscr{H}$.